# Ionic Cordova: Angualarjs double binding is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing a hybrid application by using Ionic Framework. However, my application failed in double binding when user back to hybrid application. The application able to retrieve Array Object from localstorage but my ngrepeats failed to load the var I assigned from localstorage. The following is my code.

controller.js

```
.controller('ChatsCtrl', ['$scope','$state', '$ionicTabsDelegate' , '$ionicListDelegate', '$rootScope'
    ,function($scope,$state,$ionicTabsDelegate, $ionicListDelegate, $rootScope) {

        var channel_list = [];
        channel_list =   localStorage.getItem("channel_list");
        $scope.chats = channel_list;
}])
```

HTML File

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="DRDM Chat"> 
     <div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
            <div class="h1 title">DRDM Chat</div>
    </div>
    <ion-content on-swipe-right="goBack()" on-swipe-left="goForward()">
        <br><br>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" ng-click="chatRoom({{'chat.displayName'}}, {{'chat.channelID'}})">
                <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{chat.profilePicture}}">
                <h2>{{chat.displayName}}</h2>
                <p>{{chat.lastText}}</p>
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
                <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove($index, chat.channelID)">Delete</ion-option-button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling a function on page load that re initialize your list something like this,

Controller.js

```
 $scope.init = function(){      
    var channel_list = [];
        channel_list =   localStorage.getItem("channel_list");
        $scope.chats = JSON.parse(channel_list);
    }
    $scope.init();
```

And make sure when ever you visit this page this function is fired. 
Note: if you are on the same page and wants to rebind the list then call this function in your goBack() or goForward() function where ever required.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @ChanYoongHon that's great.

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
    var channel_list = [];
    channel_list =   localStorage.getItem("channel_list");
    $scope.chats = JSON.parse(channel_list);
```

HTML file

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="DRDM Chat"> 
 <div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
        <div class="h1 title">DRDM Chat</div>
</div>
<ion-content on-swipe-right="goBack()" on-swipe-left="goForward()">
    <br><br>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" ng-click="chatRoom(chat.displayName,chat.channelID)">
            <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{chat.profilePicture}}">
            <h2>{{chat.displayName}}</h2>
            <p>{{chat.lastText}}</p>
            <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
            <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove($index, chat.channelID)">Delete</ion-option-button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

`ng-click="chatRoom(chat.displayName,chat.channelID)` Pass value like this.

Comment: Still have the same problem